# Remove key from child web.config from within parent web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

The [remove element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228241.aspx) lets you remove a key from inside the child web.config, when it's inherited from the parent web.config.  Is it possible to do the opposite?  I'd like to replace a key in the parent, that is already defined in the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't remove a key from a "child" configuration.

The inheritance goes the other way and that way only.

Define the key in the parent, as you wish, in the child remove and add it.

Comment: thanks, that was my guess but I was hoping there was another way around.